# Django perform actions after oauth callback

Tags: django, django-models, oauth, django-allauth

I have a project and I want to enable users the option to use their Google/Facebook account in order to sign up/in.

Also whenever a new user signs up another model (Account) is created and connected with that user. All of that works fine, but now I have a problem.

When users who use the Continue with Google sign up they should be redirected to the view where I will create an Account with the user that was just created (probably not the best way to do it but I can't find any examples for better ones)

Now this is where the problem occurs:

If the email already exists in Users table then the user is not being transferred to the redirect url where I will perform the checks and if the account with that email exists I will show the warning back on the login/register page but rather they get redirected to allauth's `...accounts/social/signup/` url

This is what I have:

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/account_user/checkouath/"
```

views.py

```
def checkouath(request):
    user = request.user
    oauthUser = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=user)
    # Actions to create new Account and check if User exists are going to be here

    return redirect(reverse("homepage"))
```

And this is redirect that I have set on Google: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/`

I was thinking that I can change this URL but then I get an error for an incorrect callback.

Now I'm sure this is a simple problem but I can't figure it out, I was thinking of maybe having some callback handlers but I can't find resources for implementing something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment bc of under 50 reputation but i'll remove this as soon as you respond. A few things I have to ask to try to help,

- Have you installed and included `django-social` (or whichever oauth library you're using) in main urls.py?
- The LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is supposed to be the route you redirect users after they login so that would usually be the home route or something similar. Was that your intent?
- the checkouauth function is pretty good but you can run it almost anywhere you don't necessarily need a route just for that.

Comment: Ok so I have all the libraries installed and added correctly, I figured out that if account with email thats used for logging in already exists then the user is being redirected to the custom signup (I decided not to use it for a signup but rather imitate the login my login with extra message) page from allauth, so I just created a new template for it with a message that says the custom account with this email already exists and try to log in. I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to do it but thats what worked for me and I've tested it a bit and it worked fine.

Comment: nice! I'm glad to hear that. I've done that before with several of my own apps, its pretty convenient

Comment: Yeah, but I'm pretty sure thats not the intended way lol

Comment: It's not the intended method per se, but that's the beauty of dynamic technology lol - you can expand on it and customize it to the most significant detail :)